# ADF json to sql copy empty value not inserted as null

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am attempting to copy json data to a sql table and noticed that any empty value is not being inserted as a null, even though the column is nullable. It seems to be inserting an empty string.

I have tried to add nullValue and treatEmptyAsNull parameters like the code below, but that made no difference:

```
"source": {
        "type": "BlobSource",
        "recursive": true,
        "nullValue": "",
        "treatEmptyAsNull": true
    },
```

I am expecting a null to be inserted.
Is this standard behavior for ADF copy using json as a source to not insert empty values as null? Is there other properties I need to add to the json?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value inserted into SQL db can't be null directly because your source data is empty string `""`,not null value. ADF copy activity can't convert empty string to null automatically for you.

However, you could [invoke a stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#invoke-a-stored-procedure-from-a-sql-sink) in sql server dataset. In that SP, you could convert the `""` to `null` value as you want before the columns inserted into table. Please follow the detail steps in above link or some example in my previous case:[Azure Data factory copy activity failed mapping strings (from csv) to Azure SQL table sink uniqueidentifier field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412683/azure-data-factory-copy-activity-failed-mapping-strings-from-csv-to-azure-sql).

Comment: Thanks Jay, this has cleared things up, apologies for taking so long to mark as an answer